# Stretch wallpaper across screens of different dot pitches, maintaining geometry (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, resolution, desktop-customization

I found a program called "Dual Wallpaper" that allows me to stretch pictures across monitors.

[image]

However my monitors are different dot pitches (the one on the left is 24" 1920x1200, and the one on the right is 25" 2560x1440). As you can see, the resulting image is not aligned.

[image]

Is there a program that will do what "Dual Wallpaper" does, but accounting for the different pitches, hence aligning the image across monitors?

Comment: What are the different options under Fit? And maybe Move/Zoom Image as well.

Comment: @MC10 The Fit options are for stretching / centering images, but don't account for the different pitches. However I've found I can use the Move/Zoom controls to match the two halves by eye after some trial and error, and working out the ratio between the pitches - so thanks for that. It would be good if there's some program that can do this automatically...

Comment: Sounds, good as long as it works. Btw, you may mean "resolution" or "dpi", and not "dot pitch".

Comment: If it's not too much of a hassle for you, perhaps you could post an answer with the steps you followed to get the image right. Maybe someone will see this in the future and it would be nice to see an actual answer. The comments can be confusing or ignored.