# Tile to stretch image across two monitors does not work

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

The answer to this question, does not work for me.
 [Set one background to stretch across multi-monitor display?](https://superuser.com/questions/255904/set-one-background-to-stretch-across-multi-monitor-display),
 I have found images that are supposedly large enough to handle the two 1920X1080 monitors, but when I select tile, the images always tile.
 I am running Windows 7 Professional, version 6.1.
  Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image? Would it be possible to take a picture of what the tiling looks like?

Comment: There are several other solutions on that question, have you tried them all?

Comment: @Michael Frank If you can point me to the other solutions, I would love to try them. All of the sites I found gave the same directions.

Comment: @MC10  Regarding the tiling, the image is repeated like a checkerboard multiple times on both screens. Image sizes vary, but I tried some from this site (http://wallpaperswide.com/3840x2400-wallpapers-r.html), making sure to select ones that were 3840 or greater (two monitors 1920X1080); none worked.

Comment: @pambre Strangely enough it's working for me if I choose Tile. Try a 3840x1080 wallpaper. If you're willing to use software to do it, consider this: http://superuser.com/questions/945991/stretch-wallpaper-across-screens-of-different-dot-pitches-maintaining-geometry

Comment: @MC10 I kept looking for other images and have found one that works and one that almost works (too tall). I don't know why some of the 3840s didn't work and these last two did, but I am going to keep looking for images that work. Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure, glad it was resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

You must first set the monitors in a surround setup, that is if you have and nVidia GPU, it a similar situation with AMD and Intel GPU's. You can then select an image to be stretched accross the screens. You could also cut the image in half in say photoshop and put one half on each screen.